# JS: Compare values in Array of Objects and detect matching values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, string-comparison

I have an array of objects in Javascript like:

```
    var arrobj = [
  {'id': 1, 'editors': 'Andrew||Maria', 'authors': 'Dorian||Gabi', 'agents': 'Bob||Peter'},
  {'id': 2, 'editors': 'Dorian||Guybrush', 'author': 'Peter||Frodo', 'agents': 'Dorian||Otto'},
  {'id': 3, 'editors': 'Klaus||Otmar', 'authors': 'Jordan||Morgan', 'agents': 'Jordan||Peter'},
    ];
```

I need to make a list of all people (editors, authors & agents) occurring in each object with his/her role. The output should contain a new key/value-pair ('involved') looking like this:

```
'involved': 'Andrew (editor)|| Maria (editor)|| Dorian (author) || Gabi (author) || Bob (agent) || Peter (agent)'
```

The array of objects should be something like:

```
   var arrobj = [
  {'id': 1, 'editors': 'Andrew||Maria', 'authors': 'Dorian||Gabi', 'agents': 'Bob||Peter', 'involved': 'Andrew (editor)|| Maria (editor)|| Dorian (author) || Gabi (author) || Bob (agent) || Peter (agent)'},
  {'id': 2, 'editors': 'Dorian||Guybrush', 'authors': 'Peter||Frodo', 'agents': 'Dorian||Otto','involved': 'Dorian (editor, agent) || Gybrush (editor) || Peter (author) || Frodo (author) || Otto (author)'},
  {'id': 3, 'editors': 'Klaus||Otmar', 'authors': 'Jordan||Morgan', 'agents': 'Jordan||Peter','involved': 'Klaus (editor) || Otmar (editor) || Jordan (author, agent) || Morgan (author) || Peter (agent)'},
    ];
```

If a person is associated to multiple roles (e.g. id 2 --> Dorian occurs in editors & agents), their occurrence in 'involved' should be only once but with both roles in brackets (e.g.  *Dorian (editor, agent)* )

I am very new to programming and cannot think of a way to do it properly.
At a first step I guess I have to split all values by "||" into arrays and then compare each name with every other name in the array.

I would really appreciate some help on my problem.

Comment: *"At a first step I guess I have to split all values by "||" into arrays and then compare each name with every other name in the array."* Please add that code you've tried to the question.

Comment: So you want to include a key/value pair to the current object that has pretty much the same information but in a single key/value pair entry? I don't see the point of duplicating the data when it can be easily accessed by traversing the object

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect all names with their job types and return a grouped result.

```js
 const
     getInvolved = o => {
         const
             jobs = ['editor', 'author', 'agent'],
             names = jobs.reduce((r, k) => {
                 (o[k + 's'] || '').split('||').forEach(v => (r[v] ??= []).push(k));
                 return r;
             }, {});

         return Object.entries(names).map(([k, v]) => `${k} (${v.join(', ')})`).join(' || ')
     },
     array = [{ id: 1, editors: 'Andrew||Maria', authors: 'Dorian||Gabi', agents: 'Bob||Peter' }, { id: 2, editors: 'Dorian||Guybrush', author: 'Peter||Frodo', agents: 'Dorian||Otto' }, { id: 3, editors: 'Klaus||Otmar', authors: 'Jordan||Morgan', agents: 'Jordan||Peter' }],
     result = array.map(o => ({ ...o, involved: getInvolved(o) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

- `map` the array and [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) each object to get a `roles` object without `id`.
- Create a `map` object which will map each person to an array of their roles
- Loop through each key in the `roles` object and `split` at `||` to get an array of names
- Loop through the names and update the `map` object. If the `name` hasn't been already added, add it using `||=` assignment
- Remove the last character of the role using `slice` to convert it from plural to singular ("agents" to "agent")
- The `map` object now has each person as key and an array of roles as value.

  ```js
  {
    Dorian: ["editor", "agent"],
    Guybrush: ["editor"],
    Peter: ["author"],
    Frodo: ["author"],
    Otto: ["agent"]
  }
  ```
- Loop through the entries of the object and create the `involved` string
- return a new object with an additional `involved` key

```js
const arrobj = [
  {'id': 1, 'editors': 'Andrew||Maria', 'authors': 'Dorian||Gabi', 'agents': 'Bob||Peter'},
  {'id': 2, 'editors': 'Dorian||Guybrush', 'authors': 'Peter||Frodo', 'agents': 'Dorian||Otto'},
  {'id': 3, 'editors': 'Klaus||Otmar', 'authors': 'Jordan||Morgan', 'agents': 'Jordan||Peter'},
];
    
const output = arrobj.map(({ id, ...roles }) => {
  const map = {}
  
  for (const r in roles) {
    const names = roles[r].split("||")
    for (const name of names) {
      map[name] ||= []
      map[name].push(r.slice(0,-1))
    }
  }
  
  const involved = Object.entries(map)
                         .map(([name, values]) => `${name} (${values.join(", ")})`)
                         .join(" || ")
                         
   return { id, ...roles, involved }
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of solution (ES5), there are some optimization possible. The basic idea is to push all the editors, the for the authors and agents check if it already exist in the previously composed array.

```js
var arrobj = [
  {'id': 1, 'editors': 'Andrew||Maria', 'authors': 'Dorian||Gabi', 'agents': 'Bob||Peter'},
  {'id': 2, 'editors': 'Dorian||Guybrush', 'authors': 'Peter||Frodo', 'agents': 'Dorian||Otto'},
  {'id': 3, 'editors': 'Klaus||Otmar', 'authors': 'Jordan||Morgan', 'agents': 'Jordan||Peter'},
    ];
    
function getInvolved(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(el) {
    var editors = el.editors.split('||');
    var authors = el.authors.split('||');
    var agents = el.agents.split('||'); 
    var involved = editors.map(function(editor) {
      return editor += ' (editor)';
    });
    
    authors.forEach(function(author) { 
      if(editors.indexOf(author) === -1) {
        involved.push(author + ' (author)');
      } else {
        involved = involved.map(function(inv) {
          if(inv.indexOf(author) > -1) {
            inv += '(author)';
          }
          return inv;
        });
      }
    });
    
    agents.forEach(function(agent) { 
      if(editors.indexOf(agent) === -1 && authors.indexOf(agent) === -1) {
        involved.push(agent + ' (agent)');
      } else {
        involved = involved.map(function(inv) {
          if(inv.indexOf(agent) > -1) {
            inv += '(agent)';
          }
          return inv;
        });
      }
    });
    el.involved = involved.join('||'); 
    return el;
  });
}

console.log(getInvolved(arrobj));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrobj = [
  {'id': 1, 'editors': 'Andrew||Maria', 'authors': 'Dorian||Gabi', 'agents': 'Bob||Peter'},
  {'id': 2, 'editors': 'Dorian||Guybrush', 'authors': 'Peter||Frodo', 'agents': 'Dorian||Otto'},
  {'id': 3, 'editors': 'Klaus||Otmar', 'authors': 'Jordan||Morgan', 'agents': 'Jordan||Peter'},
];

for (let obj of arrobj) {
  obj.involved = "";
  for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    let strKey = [...key];
    strKey.pop();
    let role = strKey.join("");
    if (key === "involved") break;
    if (key !== "id") {
      obj.involved += obj[key]
        .split("||")
        .map((name) => name + "(" + role + ")||")
        .join("");
    }
    obj.involved = obj.involved.substr(0, obj.involved.length - 2).trim();
  }
}

console.log(arrobj);
```

here is the running repl: https://repl.it/join/juljqzxt-theketan2

Comment: The output is not correct. If a person has more than one role, they want to group it like: `Dorian (editor, agent)`

Comment: I didn't assumed that but that can be easily implemented. Thanks for heads up 